# Seemingly easy FNV1 hashing implementation results in a lot of collisions

Tags: java, hash

I'm playing with hash tables and using a corpus of ~350,000 English words which I'd like to try to evenly distribute. Thus, I try to fit them into an array of length 810,049 (the closest prime larger than two times the input size) and I was baffled to see that a straightforward FNV1 implementation like this:

```
public int getHash(String s, int mod) {
        final BigInteger MOD = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(mod));
        final BigInteger FNV_offset_basis = new BigInteger("14695981039346656037");
        final BigInteger FNV_prime = new BigInteger("1099511628211");

        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(FNV_offset_basis.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int charValue = s.charAt(i);

            hash = hash.multiply(FNV_prime).mod(MOD);
            hash = hash.xor(BigInteger.valueOf((int) charValue & 0xffff)).mod(MOD);
        }

        return hash.mod(MOD).intValue();
    }
```

results in 64,000 collisions which is *a lot*, 20% of the input basically. What's wrong with my implementation? Is the approach somehow flawed?

EDIT: to add to that, I've also tried and implemented other hashing algorithms like sdbm and djb2 and they all perform *just the same*, equally poorly. All have these ~65k collisions on this corpus. When I changed the corpus to just 350,000 integers represented as strings, a bit of variance starts to occur (like one algorithms has 20,000 collisions and the other has 40,000) but still the number of collision is astoundingly high. Why?

EDIT2: I've just tested it and the Java's built-in .hashCode() results in equally as many collisions and even if you do something ridiculously naive, like a hash being a product of multiplicating charcodes of all the characters modulo 810,049, it performs only half worse than all those notorious algorithms (60k collisions vs. 90k with the naive approach).

Comment: What do you intend for the caller to pass as `mod`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `mod` is a parameter to *your* hash function I presume it is the range into which you want the hash normalized, i.e. for your specific use case you are expecting it to be `810,049`.   I assume this because:

1. The algorithm calls for the calculations to be done modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where *n* is the number of bits in the desired hash.
2. Given that the *offset basis* and *FNV Prime* are constants within the module, and are equal to the parameters for a 64-bit hash, the value of `mod` should also be fixed at 2<sup>64</sup>.
3. Since it is not, I assume it is the desired final output range.

In other words, given a fixed offset basis and FNV Prime, there is no reason to pass in the mod parameter -- it is dictated by the other two FNV parameters.
If all the above is correct then the implementation is wrong. You should be doing the calculations mod 2<sup>64</sup> and applying a final remainder operation with 810,049.

Also (but this may not be important), the algorithm calls for xoring the lower 8 bits with an ASCII character, whereas you are xoring with 16 bits.  I am not sure this will make a difference since for ASCII the high-order byte will be zero anyway and it will behave exactly as if you were xoring only 8 bits.

Comment: Yep, `mod` is the expected range which is `810,049`. As for the rest of your reply, of course you're right that FNV should be using 2^64 as the modulus but since I'm going to mod it with `810,049` in the end, this doesn't seem like a problem, does it? Even if it does, though, as it turned out (which I added in the edit in the main post), the problem is hardly FNV-specific since regardless of the algorithm used, a similar (and similarly high at that ) number of collisions persists.